# "Stack Overflow en español" y no "en Español" en el logo

Tags: discusión

El título de este sitio es "Stack Overflow en español". Sin embargo, el logo utiliza mayúsculas en el idioma: *Español* en lugar de *español*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dado que en castellano los idiomas se escriben en minúscula, ¿no sería correcto actualizar el logo para que la palabra español fuera escrita así?

Comment: Caramba mira que busqué y no encontré quien lo hubiera preguntado antes. Gracias @Pablo