# Los enlaces en la explicación de duplicados en Meta no tienen el markdown correcto

Tags: bug, estado-completado, cierre-de-preguntas, meta

El mensaje que ve un usuario en sus propias preguntas que han sido marcadas como duplicadas de otra/s es el siguiente:

> Esta pregunta fue **marca** como un duplicado exacto de una pregunta existente. Si esta pregunta es diferente, por favor **[edítala] (/posts/232/edit)** para explicar en que difiere o **[realiza una nueva pregunta] (/questions/ask)**.

Esto me pasa a mí con las dos que tengo ([1](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/232/83) y [2](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/246/83)). En ambos casos es duplicada exacta de otra pregunta y yo usé el [auto dupe-hammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/209901) confirmando el voto de clausura que otros iniciaron).

Además de *marca* que debería ser *marcada*, el problema es que el mensaje que sale contiene un markdown incorrecto en los dos enlaces al haber un espacio entre el texto y la dirección:

- `[edítala] (/posts/232/edit)` tiene un espacio entre `]` y `(`. Si lo quitamos tendríamos `[edítala](/posts/232/edit)`, que se convierte en → [edítala](/posts/232/edit).
- `[realiza una nueva pregunta] (/questions/ask)` al que le pasa lo mismo. Quitando ese espacio de más tendríamos → [realiza una nueva pregunta](/questions/ask).

Nótese que este comentario solo lo ve el propietario de la pregunta, tal y como se menciona en los comentarios. Para reproducirlo, mira [tus preguntas duplicadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ayes+user%3Ame)... sí, de tú que estás leyendo.

Nótese que esto lo he observado en Meta. Ignoro si también sucede en el sitio principal. Mira a ver si tienes alguna [pregunta duplicada allí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ayes+user%3Ame) y nos dices :)

Comment: ¿Será que son preguntas "antiguas"? Creo que sería bueno que agregaras una captura de pantalla, pues para ver esto, los demás tendríamos que buscar preguntas propias que hayan sido marcadas como duplicado. Por otro lado, sería bueno comparar entre preguntas marcadas como duplicados que sean viejas  con nuevas

Comment: @Rubén buena idea. Investigué un poco y el texto es consistente entre las viejas y las nuevas, solamente mis dos preguntas son las que tienen este texto. ¿Probablemente se estuvo haciendo pruebas?

Comment: Pude reproducirlo. No es un tema de qué pregunta sea, sino de **quién es el autor de la pregunta**. En mi pregunta marcada como duplicada el 25/4/17: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/75/127, puedo ver el texto con markdown incorrecto. Este mensaje parece mostrarse sólo al autor.

Comment: @Mariano ¡gracias! Esto tiene más sentido, me extrañaba ser el único... no soy tan importante jaja. Reformulado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¡El markdown se ha corregido! Si encuentran otras traducciones que no son adecuadas, favor de avisarnos.

Comment: En [Reemplazar endiduras por sangrado o por indentación en artículo de ayuda mcve](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1555/65) se sigue mostrando el markdown en lugar de los enlaces. ¿Ya debería haberse corregido?

Comment: Se necesita esperar unas cuantas horas antes de verificar el cambio.  Cada vez que cambiamos algo en la base de datos hay que esperar al siguiente "build" para que el cambio tome efecto.

Comment: Ya quedó listo :)

Comment: Qué bien, ¡muchas gracias por resolverlo!

Answer (score 0):

Usé [user:me duplicate:yes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3A65%20duplicate%3Ayes) me muestra 4 preguntas. En unas se muestra el problema, pero en otras no. A continuación un ejemplo de cada caso:

[En el seguimiento de medallas no se muestran todas las etiquetas en las que participo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1406/65)

[image]

[Reemplazar endiduras por sangrado o por indentación en artículo de ayuda mcve](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1555/65)

[image]

Comment: Uhms, qué raro. Además, ambas se cerraron como duplicado de una pregunta solamente y en fechas parecidas. Y además, te sale bien en la que marcaste tú como duplicada (Community) y mal en la que fue con votos de otra gente. En mi caso yo la marqué como duplicada...

Comment: La diferencia entre estas dos es que la segunda tiene la descripción de "duplicado exacto". Sólo parecería estar mal en ese caso.

Comment: @Mariano la gracia es que mis dos preguntas caen en el primer caso: alguien sugiere un duplicado exacto y yo lo confirmo, por lo que sale el usuario Community. Y precisamente ese caso es el que le sale bien a Rubén :O